# Create a copy from "this" pointer and changing the copy without affecting "this" C++

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I have this function and I can't modify it

```
Image z("abc.jpg");
Image g = z.change();
```

in function Change, I need to return a new value in g without affecting z.

My main **problem** is in the next function

```
Image Image::change(){
    Image temp = *this;
    ...
    temp.image[i][j] = mean; // here also this->image[i][j] changed to the same value
}
```

in this function whenever I change temp , this changes and this is not what I want

the copy constructor

```
Image::Image(const Image &obj):imageHeader("Temp")
{
    width = obj.width;
    height = obj.height;
    image = obj.image;
    imageHeader = obj.imageHeader;
}
```

Comment: Then fix the `Image` class so it doesn't do that.

Comment: We need to see the full code of `Image`, and possibly of resources it owns, to help you with this problem.

Comment: Write the copy constructor correctly. Without seeing it, I can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: You have written your `Image` class (maybe inadvertently) so that instances of it shares resources with copies made of that instance.

Comment: Given that we don't know how `Image` class is actually implemented, it's very hard to say how to fix this. But my guess is that you have't followed "rule of three", and you're allocating memory in the constructor, but then directly copying the pointers/references to that in your copy constructor (or haven't got a copy constructor)

Comment: @AhmedShaher - What you posted is not a copy constructor.  A copy constructor takes a reference, not a pointer as an argument.

Comment: Please stop posting fake code.

Comment: @AhmedShaher - You could never have fixed it, since a reference uses `.` syntax, not `->` syntax.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Forgot to fix that here , sorry

Comment: @BenjaminLindley it's not .

Comment: @AhmedShaher - To really answer your question, we need to see what needs to be copied.  You never showed us what `image` and `imageheader` are or even what types `width` and `height` are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a *deep copy*. You need to implement a copy constructor for the class `Image`.

EDIT: The copy constructor that you provided only copies a pointer to the image data instead of copying the data itself (among other issues). This is why you see this behavior.

A signature for such a function would look as follows:

```
Image(const Image &img) 
{ 
    //copy static members normally and manage data to allocate memory for dynamic members
    width = img.width;
    height = img.height;
    imageHeader = img.imgHeader;
    image = //do something to dynamically allocate the image data here
}
```

Note also that the rule of three states that you'll probably need a destructor and assignment operator as well.

Comment: It's better to have the class only contain member variables with value semantics, so that none of those three functions are required. Look up "Rule of Zero".   The rule of three is so last century :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I guess you're saying that the image should really wrapped in some sort of handle class? I'd agree, but chances are that OP is stuck using some old library that doesn't offer that functionality.

Comment: Can you please explain more what do you mean with "dynamically allocate a new image "

Comment: Whatever code is required to add that functionality, put it in its own minimal class and make that be the member variable

Comment: @AhmedShaher you have not provided any information so far about what `image` or `imageHeader` are or how they came to be; those are important details

Comment: @AhmedShaher You'll likely need to use the new[] operator to dynamically allocate memory. You'll also have to be sure to delete this memory once you're done with it. If `image` is a class it could be as simple as saying `image = new img_data(...params...)`

Comment: @Adam27X: No one needs to use `new[]` to allocate memory, except the library developers who maintain `std::vector` and `std::make_unique`.

Comment: @Adam27X apparently i lake main concepts in oop. Can you help with some resources ?

Comment: @AhmedShaher It's not so much OOP as it is the difference between pointers, references as well as between shallow and deep copies. One book I would recommend is Accelerated C++, but this topic has been covered well on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy

Answer (score 0):

What you have "should" work, but only if you have a useful copy constructor. We really need to see what is going on inside Image, but my guess is it looks something like

```
class Image {
    void* bytesOfPixelData; // maybe a char* or some sort of char[][]
}
```

When you set `Image temp = *this`, it just copies your *pointer*. And since the pointer is shared, then the changes are shared. Classes with pointers in them need more intelligent copy constructors when you want to do a **deep copy.** Just copying the pointer does a **shallow copy.** In a case like this, your copy constructor needs to allocate another data buffer and copy the data. The details of that depend on your implementation, which isn't posted.

See also [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) (or Rule of Five in C++11), for correct design of `Image`.

Comment: I added the copy constructor

Comment: @AhmedShaher If you're talking abut the function you added to your original post, that is *not* a copy constructor.

Comment: Better yet, apply "The Rule of Zero" and use `std::vector` to manage the buffer.

Comment: @BenVoigt Excellent point, although it is possible this is an exercise in learning about copy ctors.